# Finding words that start/end with input letters (tiles) from the user in a file

Tags: python, cpu-word

So I've been trying to implement a Scrabble word game, and part of that is for me to be able to find words that start and end with one or more letters (or tiles since this is scrabble) entered by a user. There is a words.txt file that contains all of the words.

Really have no idea how to implement it with more than one letter. I'd prefer a loop that reads through the file line by line and then checks with the users input. But other function based answers are fine too!

Thanks!

P.S: It's my first post here so I apologize if I did not ask correctly

Comment: Could you show your implementation with one letter and your attempts at amending it to support more than one? Others can then help you understand why your existing code doesn't work. Sadly, without any code - this question does look somewhat "Please write some code for me"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following solution. The user has to enter some letters and the program looks, whether those letters can be found at the beginning or end of a word.

```
with open('words.txt') as f:
    wordlist = [line.strip().lower() for line in f]

from itertools import permutations
while True:
    userinput = raw_input("Please enter your letters: ").lower()
    # look up any combinations of letters
    for letter_permutation in permutations(userinput):
        s = ''.join(letter_permutation)
        for word in wordlist:
            if word.startswith(s) or word.endswith(s):
                print "'%s' is part of %s" % (s, word)
    if raw_input('Press q to exit, any key to continue... ').lower() == 'q':
        break
```

For small length of userinput, you can also create a tuple with all permutations, but since its size would increase with the factorial of the length, I would suggest to use the solution above. But for the sake of showing cool python stuff. (Thanks to Jon Clements for advise to use `str.startswith` or `str.endswith` with tuples)

```
while True:
    userinput = raw_input("Please enter your letters: ").lower()
    # create a tuple with all combinations of letters
    perms = tuple( ''.join(letter_permutation)
                   for letter_permutation in permutations(userinput) )
    # now check if any of the words starts or ends with any of the letter-perms
    for word in wordlist:
        # startswith, endswith also take tuples as arguments
        if word.startswith(perms) or word.endswith(perms):
            print "'%s' can be found in %s" % (userinput, word)

    if raw_input('Press q to exit, any key to continue... ').lower() == 'q':
        break
```

Comment: Could just use a list-comp such as `wordlist = [line.strip().lower() for line in f]` instead of the generator and then materialising with `list`. You can also remove the outer loop here - pre-compute the permutations into a tuple.... `perms = tuple(''.join(p) for p in permuations(userinput))`.... then in your `for word in wordlist:` take advantage of the fact that `str.startswith` and `str.endswith` accept tuples... `if word.startswith(perms) or word.endswith(perms)`....

Comment: @JonClements Are you sure that there is a difference between `list(x for x in X)` and `[x for sin X]`. In my eyes both are list comprehensions…
But thanks for mentioning that `str.startswith` takes tuples, too. Think about using it...

Comment: The second is an actual list-comp. The first is a call to a function called `list` (hopefully the builtin one) with a generator as its sole argument. That in this case happens to build a list. So while the end results are both lists the underlying mechanism/implementation differs.

Comment: Having said all that - if you factor out the outerloop you only need to loop once over the file, so you can do that directly instead of putting it in a list anyway...

Comment: @JonClements I was not aware of that, thank. I also checked the byte bytecode for both `list(…)` and `[]` and it differs, the byte code for `list(...)` is actually longer. Thanks

Comment: @JonClements No, I don't want to open and search the file each time the user wants to check a word. If it was a one-shot program I would agree, but as you see it is not...

Comment: Since you've got an input loop I agree it makes complete sense. My bad - I was thinking in terms of the OPs rather loose description ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! @JonClements I'm sorry if my question seemed to be asking for someone to write code for me. I didn't realize I had to post my previous code up till the point I was stuck at. Now that I think about it, it makes sense. Thanks so much for helping out with this!

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you're trying to accomplish, can you give more detail by editing your post?

I'm trying to extrapolate that you're checking the played word against a wordlist you have somewhere? No need to check words that start with one or more letters, just read the whole word into a variable and..

```
word = readTheWord() #read the word into the variable
if word in wordlist: #for some wordlist dictionary
  #accept the input
else:
  #deny the input
```

Is this what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Which part are you stuck on?

Google a tutorial on how to read a file line-by-line, if you haven't got that far yet.

Make sure the file is sorted alphabetically. If there aren't too many words, load them all into memory at the start of the program. Do a binary search with your input string. If there's no exact match, it should give you back an index where the word would fit. From there, scan forwards and backwards to find all words [starting with](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) your input string. This should take O(n log n) time instead of linear time.

Make a copy of the word list, reverse every string, including your input string, and then repeat the above to find words ending with your input string.